# .net xml schema validation on wrong namespace

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

Having XML schema with the namespace `http://mynamespace`. If the wrong XML document with default namespace `xmlns="http://mynamespace"` is validated then exception is thrown as expected. While if someone change the namespace(`http://Wrongnamespace`) this **wrong XML will pass validation**.

Here is the unit test with schema validation. Method `XSD_NotValid_2` is not working properly:

```
[TestClass]
public class XSDTest
{
    public System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings ReaderSettings
    {
        get
        {
            string sXSD = "<xsd:schema targetNamespace=\"http://mynamespace\" xmlns=\"http://mynamespace\""
                + " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" elementFormDefault=\"qualified\">"
            + "<xsd:element name=\"Root\">"
            + "<xsd:complexType>"
                + "<xsd:sequence>"
                    + "<xsd:element name=\"Child\" minOccurs=\"1\" maxOccurs=\"1\" />"
                + "</xsd:sequence>"
             + "</xsd:complexType>"
            + "</xsd:element>"
            + "</xsd:schema>";

            System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(new System.IO.StringReader(sXSD)
                        , new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(OnValidationFail));

            System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings readerSettings_Ret = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings_Ret.ValidationType = System.Xml.ValidationType.Schema;
            readerSettings_Ret.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(OnValidationFail);
            readerSettings_Ret.Schemas.Add(schema);

            return readerSettings_Ret;
        }
    }


    private void OnValidationFail(object s, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException("Validation error: " + e.Message);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void XSD_Valid_Test()
    {
         // Valid elements and valid namespace
        String sXML_Valid = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<Root xmlns=\"http://mynamespace\"><Child /></Root>";
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader_Valid = 
            System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(sXML_Valid), this.ReaderSettings);
        while (xmlReader_Valid.Read()) { } // no fail expected
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(OperationCanceledException))]
    public void XSD_NotValid_1()
    {
         // No valid elements, while valid namespace
        String sXML_NotValid_1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<BadRoot xmlns=\"http://mynamespace\"><Child /></BadRoot>";
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader_NoValid_1 = 
            System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(sXML_NotValid_1), this.ReaderSettings);
        while (xmlReader_NoValid_1.Read()) ;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(OperationCanceledException))]
    public void XSD_NotValid_2()
    {
        // No valid elements and no valid namespace
        String sXML_NotValid_2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<Root xmlns=\"http://Wrongnamespace\"><NotValidChild /></Root>";
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader_NoValid_2 = 
            System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(sXML_NotValid_2), this.ReaderSettings);
        while (xmlReader_NoValid_2.Read()) ;
    }
}
```

Is it normal behavior? How to force correct namespace targeting? 
And also how to force `Root` element to be required in the case XSD has additional `Root2` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable schema validation warnings, you'll get the following error:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'http://Wrongnamespace:Root'.

Use

```
readerSettings_Ret.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

A couple of small things:

1. Even in a unit test, you shouldn't be creating XML by string manipulation. Always use XML APIs to create XML, as they know "all the rules".
2. Even in a unit test, you should place your creation of objects that implement IDisposable in `using` blocks. In fact, I'd say *especially* in a unit test, where each test should be independent of the other tests, you want to make sure that one test has cleaned up before starting the next.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Of course I built XSD in VS. It is only for presentation purpose and fast copy paste.